# Save results from query and store it in JSON file format, then return it - Laravel / Vue

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm making an api in Laravel to communicate with Vue on the front-end.

First I don't want to make a request to the database everytime the page is loaded.

**Solution** : Make the first request to the database, save to a json file and then return it, the next request will only send the json file without a database request. I ll be regenerated after 1 day.

**Problem** : Everything is working but the response its not in an valid json format. So Vue can't cacth the json file and render the page

Code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Product;
use Storage;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function home () 
    {
        $file = 'json\products.json';
        $fileExists = Storage::disk('local')->exists( $file );
        $storagePath  = Storage::disk('local')->path( $file );

        if ( $fileExists ) {
            if ( time () - 86400 < filemtime ($storagePath ) ) {
                return Storage::get($file);
            }
        }

        $products = Product::select( 'id' , 'name' , 'code' , 'description' , 'size' , 'weight' , 'pic_url' 'pic_video' 'long_description' )->limit(200)->get();

        //Storage::disk('local')->put('json\products.json', json_encode($products, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ); //Doesnot Work 
        Storage::disk('local')->put('json\products.json', response()->json(['products' => $products ])); // Doesnot Work

        return response()->json(['products' => $products ] , 200); // This response works , and vue catches and reads perfectly
    }
}
```

edited : return Storage::get($file);

[Example in browser:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjea8.png)

Comment: you know, you could just use `return ['products' => $products];` and it would return JSON right

Comment: Doing this ? Storage::disk('local')->put('json\products.json', ['products' => $products] ); -> Doesnot work.

Comment: No, I meant as your final return

Comment: Also `json\products.json` is not a valid folder location

Comment: No, I meant as your final return -> that not the problem here. The problem is in here : return Storage::get($file);

Comment: Its all working - by that I mean the paths - I render the url direct via the api laravel path and the content its not in a valid json format. Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved like this:

```
return cache()->remember($cacheKey, 1440 , function () {
    $products = Product::select( 'id' , 'name' , 'code' , 'description' , 'size' , 'weight' , 'pic_url' 'pic_video' 'long_description' )->limit(200)->get();
    return ['products' => $products];
});
```